# VBA UpdateListItems SharePoint WebService

Tags: sharepoint, vba, soap

I'm trying to create a new task in a SharePoint list in VBA.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
Public Sub AddToSharePoint(ByVal Title As String, ByVal URL As String)
  Dim oSoapClient As Object
  Const ListID As String = "{0533218A-7FD9-4A25-AB8B-640F43E99741}"
  Const ListView As String = "{805F724A-C3BD-4F26-891F-A331A469BC35}"

  Dim BatchXML As String

  BatchXML = "<Batch OnError='continue' ListVersion='1' ViewName='" & ListView & "'>"
  BatchXML = BatchXML & "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>"

  BatchXML = BatchXML & "<Field Name='Title'>" & Title & "</Field>"

  BatchXML = BatchXML & "</Method></Batch>"

  Set oSoapClient = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SOAPClient30")
  oSoapClient.MSSoapInit URL&"?WSDL"

  oSoapClient.UpdateListItems ListID, BatchXML

  Set oSoapClient = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Everything works well until the line:

```
oSoapClient.UpdateListItems ListID, BatchXML
```

Coming to this line I've got an error which says:

> Maximum retry on the connection exceeded (80004005)

I can't figure it out what's wrong here.

Comment: What is the value of `URL` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

One first step in solving your problem is to look at the exact nature of the UpdateListItems function's parameters.

=> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx

As you can see : 
- The first parameter must be a string containing the name of your Sharepoint List
- The second one should be an XMLNode of the  component (and not just a String).

I can't help more, because I'm also stuck on this problem a little bit farther (Execution Error : SoapServerException was thrown).
But that's still a first step ;)